# How to calculate after-tax return if investor can use capital loss, in Canada?

Tags: taxes, canada, bonds

> [[Source:]](http://www.theglobeandmail.com/globe-investor/investor-education/bonds-or-gics-for-taxable-investors-the-choice-is-clear/article5356721/) [As you can see in the table](http://www.theglobeandmail.com/globe-investor/investor-education/bonds-or-gics-the-choice-is-easy/article5356884/?from=5356721), the $105,000 government bond matures at $100,000, for a capital loss of $5,000. The investor would also collect interest totalling $9,660 over the three years ($100,000 x 0.0322 x 3). But here’s the thing: Even though the capital loss takes a big bite out of the investor’s return, the entire $9,660 in interest payments is taxable at the investor’s marginal rate (which is assumed here to be **46.41%**).
>
> The tax hit works out to $4,483. If you subtract that amount, and the $5,000 capital loss, from the $9,660, in interest the investor is left with an after-tax return of just $177. True, he could theoretically use the capital loss to offset other capital gains – assuming he has them – but that would only boost the net return to $1,337, which is still pretty lousy. **True, he could theoretically use the capital loss to offset other capital gains – assuming he has them – but that would only boost the net return to $1,337, which is still pretty lousy**.

[image: [Source:]](http://www.theglobeandmail.com/globe-investor/investor-education/bonds-or-gics-for-taxable-investors-the-choice-is-clear/article5356721/)]

To calculate the after-tax return with the use of $5,000 capital loss, why perform the arithmetic coloured in orange above? To wit, why multiply $5000 x 50% x 46.41%?
I know that the article assumes 46.41% as the investor's marginal tax rate.

Answer (score 2):

Capital gains have what's called a [50% inclusion rate](http://www.cra-arc.gc.ca/tx/ndvdls/tpcs/ncm-tx/rtrn/cmpltng/rprtng-ncm/lns101-170/127/glssry-eng.html#InclusionrateIR).  IOW only 50% of the gain is taxable.

It's this rate that makes premium bonds a bad investment.  If interest and capital gains were taxed at the same rate, it wouldn't matter.  OTOH it's a great time to buy discount bonds if you can find them.

The inclusion rate can change.  In 1990 it was 75%, before that it was ~67% for a time.  We have this rate because it's somewhat unfair (if this word can ever apply to taxes) to tax long term capital gains at 100% since much of the gain can be due to inflation.  As such, it's not a real gain.

Comment: +1. Thanks, but because the orange calculates the AFTER-tax return, why is the taxable gain (50% x 2500) multiplied by 46.41% Should it NOT be multiplied by (100 ― 46.41)%?

Comment: It's actually a capital loss.  If it goes unused forever the after tax return is the $177.  They are saying if you can use the loss, it will net you $5000*50%*46%.  I'm guessing the (100-46%) you wrote is implying you get to keep ~54% of the taxable amount of a capital GAIN, which is true.  You may be confusing "what you owe" with "what you keep".